# How do I assign a checked list box to List object?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, list, checklistbox

I have a object that accepts string array, so I am passing:

```
Dim listM As New List(Of String)
listM.Add(TextBox7.Text)
MyMEqRequest.MP = listM.ToArray()
```

But now I have a`CheckedListBox` where I select multiple values. I want to assign that to this `MyMEqRequest.MP` and for that I need to loop through the list which I don't want, I want to directly assign it.

Comment: `CheckedListBox` or `CheckBoxList`?  Not the same thing.  One is Windows Forms and the other is ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: Either way, you're dealing with a list.  You have to loop through that list and get each individual value, then add it to your `List(Of String)` in exactly the same way as you already are.  This is why you need to break problems down into parts.  Your issue has nothing to do with the `List(Of String)` because you already know how to use that.  Your issue is getting the information you need out of your source list.  What you do with it is irrelevant to how you get it out.

Comment: add to ANSWER BOX I WILL ACCEPT AS AN ANSWER

Comment: There's not enough information there for an answer.  It's just a push in the right direction.